# Problem with figure and minipage

Tags: tables, graphics, floats, minipage, wrapfigure

I'm currently writing a paper using LaTeX, I would like to add some figures and texts in between two paragraphs.

However, when 3 figures and text reaches to the bottom, "This is the second paragraph" and "This is the second paragraph" somehow shows up before the figure 4 and text are done showing. How should I solve this problem?

Really appreciate for your help!

```
\section{Introduction}

This is the first part of the introduction, This is the first part of the introduction, This is the first part of the introduction.

%% figure 1 and text
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[%scale=1
                 width=0.75\linewidth, valign=t]{figures/Picture 1.jpg}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\textbf{Topic 1}  \\
This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph,
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

%% figure 2 and text
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[%scale=1
                 width=0.75\linewidth, valign=t]{figures/Picture 2.jpg}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\textbf{Topic 2}  \\
This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph,
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

%% figure 3 and text
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[%scale=1
                 width=0.75\linewidth, valign=t]{figures/Picture 3.jpg}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\textbf{Topic 3}  \\
This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph,
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

%% figure 4 and text
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[%scale=1
                 width=0.75\linewidth, valign=t]{figures/Picture 4.jpg}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\textbf{Topic 4}  \\
This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph, This is a Paragraph,
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

This is the second paragraph, this is the second paragraph, this is the second paragraph

This is the third paragraph, this is the third paragraph, this is the third paragraph
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Could you please make your code compilable (i.e. provide the documentclass and the list of packages stripped down to the bare minimum that you need to use to compile this snippet) so that other people can reproduce your result and help you improve it.

Comment: ""This is the second paragraph" somehow shows up before the figure 4 and text are done showing. How should I solve this problem?" that is not a problem, it is the only reason to use `figure` to allow its content to be moved to help page breaking. If you do not want that, delete `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`

Comment: `figure`s (like `table`s) are floating parts of the document. If they don't fit on the page, and with `ht` it means here or at the top of a page, they float to a next page. There are also some parameters that restrict how many floats, and their size, is allowed on a page. See http://tug.ctan.org/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#Floats